Post Hoc Test after Chi Square and Alternative to Chi Square
A user can choose one of four categories A, B, C and D. I would like to know if there is one category that is chosen more often than another one. I chose a Chi-Square test for that.
Next, I would like to know which of the categories are chosen more often. For that I would to pairwise posthoc tests and adjust for multiple comparisons.

Question 1: Which posthoc test is appropriate? My intuition tells me that I can perform pairwise binomial tests, but my intuition can be wrong.
Question 2: What is an alternative to the Chisquare test if I have less than five observations per category?

Here is what I have so far in Python:
from itertools import combinations
from scipy.stats import binomtest
from scipy.stats import chisquare
from statsmodels.stats.multitest import multipletests

counts = [208, 174, 149, 18]

print(f"pvalue={chisquare(counts).pvalue:.5f}\n")
labels = list(combinations(["A", "B", "C", "D"], r=2))
combs = list(combinations(counts, r=2))

pvals = [binomtest(c1, c1+c2, p=0.5).pvalue for c1, c2 in combs]
pvals = multipletests(pvals)[1]
for (l1, l2), p in zip(labels, pvals):
    print(l1, l2, f"p={p:.5f}")

Result:
pvalue=0.00000

A B p=0.17408
A C p=0.00629
A D p=0.00000
B C p=0.18166
B D p=0.00000
C D p=0.00000

